# GitLab/Github and Deploy Keys

Tags: git, gitlab, сервер, github

помогите пожалуйста разобраться. 
Сейчас есть у меня локальный проект, который пушится в GitLab. 
в данном случае origin у меня идет мой удаленный хост на гитлабе.

задача состоит в том, чтобы теперь весь проект на удаленном репозитории гитлаба вытолкнуть на сервер , где должен хранится сайт (проект).

вычитала, что для этого нужно сгенирировать ключ и вставить в гитлабе в настройках проекта во вкладку Deploy Keys

я через ssh-keygen на своем сервере сгенерила, ключ вставила, то есть ключ как бы аутентифицирует меня на сервере без ввода пароля как я поняла.

теперь не могу понять как мне вытолкнуть мой удаленный репозиторий с гитлаба на мой сервер?

и нужен ли на сервере для этого установленный гит? (мои админы говорят что не нужен как бы и изменять репозиторий на диплойдном сервере не стоит)

один из вариантов который более менее логичный я думаю - это что-то git clone git@cvs.lan:user/test.git user@testhost.ru, но не понимает, копирует все в папку на локале но никак не на сервере, и инфу найти подобную не могу.

Что вы посоветуете? просто варианты пробы кончились, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: > и нужен ли на сервере для этого установленный гит

я бы делал через гит, но можно и зипом вытаскивать определенный бранч (если совсем никак), вот, нпрмр, сам гитлаб 6.6: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/repository/archive.zip?ref=6-6-stable

> диплойдном

0_0

> это что-то git clone git@cvs.lan:user/test.git user@testhost.ru, но не понимает, копирует все в папку на локале но никак не на сервере

Сервер сам должен вытянуть проект, как будто он - еще один пользователь. Deploy key - это такой же ssh-ключ, только он дает доступ не конкретному пользователю, а просто предоставившему ключ.

Comment: правильно ли поняла я:

то есть на сервере я делаю git pull git@cvs.lan:user/test.git и в данном случае деплой кей мне нужен чтобы не вводить логин и пароль, а сразу тянул мой репозиторий?

Comment: @ennet, я с деплой-ключами не работал, но по описаниям все должно быть именно так. Можно по ssh зайти на сервер и оттестировать это в ручном режиме.

Comment: @ennet, 

> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on the server and grants access to a single repository on GitHub. This key is attached directly to the repository instead of to a user account.

это не имеет отношения к серверу как я понимаю, это просто позволяет делать коммит без юзера.

Comment: чтобы деплоить с github есть хуки,

Comment: угу поняла, не знаете где есть точный код как писать Post-Receive URLs для моего проекта?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Развёртывание git репозитория](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516662/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-git-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f)