# Клонирование не работает для GitLab-сервера в локальной сети

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

Сервер GitLab развернут во внутренней сети с ip 192.168.0.1

Также есть внешний сервер 82.140.xx.xx

далее на сервере делается клонирование удаленного репозитория:

```
git clone git@gitlab.lan:h4/private_repo.git
```

соответственно он выдает ошибку, что не знает хост gitlab.lan

Читала, что для того, чтобы склонировать мой репозиторий из гитлаба на сервере, нужно на сервере сгенерить SSH ключи и добавить в гитлаб в deploy key. Я думала, что deploy key решает эту проблему, но это не так.

Как решить проблему с `git clone`?

Обязательно ли, чтобы мой 192.168.0.1 был внешним??

Comment: ну это естественно... как иначе по ssh невозможно за нат пробиться, есть способ, называется vpn. вы наоборот сделайте :) 

на сервере 

    git init 

дома - 

   git push

Comment: получается мне пушить сначала на гитлаб изменения (он  уменя оригин)? а потом допустим добавить удаленный репозиторий на сервер и после пушить туда? правильно ли поняла?)

Comment: > я думала деплой кей решает эту проблему, что подскажите?

Deploy key - это способ для машины представиться гитхабу/гитлабу

> тут железно надо , чтобы мой 192.168.0.1 был внешним??

Да, **если** обязательно разворачивать прямо с гитлаба на сервер. @eicto написал пару методов, где сервак гитлаба так и остается внутри сетки, другое дело что при этом автоматизация процесса станет сложнее. Но вообще гит должен уметь обмениваться данными и без центрального сервака гитлаба/гитхаба, вы действительно можете перебрасывать коммиты напрямую, минуя гитлаб. Все зависит от подробностей задачи.

Comment: да надо чтоб он был внутренним гитлаб, а сервак внешним. читла еще про веб хуки, но там тоже проблема в том, что он внутренний мой гитлаб. спасибо за ответы!)

Comment: у gitlab/git есть просто хуки, это скрипты выполняемые по каким нибудь событиям.

Comment: нету ли у вас случайно примера хуков, где бы скрипт брал изменения в локальном гитлабе и пушил бы на внешний сервер ? то что я искала в гугле, для этого нужен внешний гитлаб

Comment: расскажите подробнее про ваш процесс, может локальный gitlab не нужен (хватит просто git)? вообще там миллион способов, например на update локального сервера он просто делает push на внешний сервер.

---

@ennet я здесь отвечу, нет - этот способ для того чтобы информировать удаленный сервер http хуком с github, т.е. у вас где-то есть веб сервер и вы на него деплоите, вам надо по другому. вам нужно написать хук на локальном сервере, который будет делать пуш

Comment: вот да ваш вариант, у нас стоит локальный gitlab, нужно именно пушить через него, чтобы  было автоматизировано. нашла в сети вариант , что пушишь на локальный и пушится сразу на сервер. вот он http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/prostoy-avtomaticheskiy-deploy-iz-repozitorija-github как бы попробовала и просто не видит айпишник моего внешнего, хотя я ключ добавила. как то так. мож я где просто торможу?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/253713#253720 вот на основе такого скрипта можно что нить придумать, он немного сыроват и с тех пор я уже много другого делал, но для понимания сойдет (rsync можно и на удаленный сервер делать, или вообще на push заменить)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [GitLab/Github and Deploy Keys](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299702/gitlab-github-and-deploy-keys)