# Развёртывание git репозитория

Tags: git, развертывание, git-clone

Есть репозиторий `test`, на сервере он лежит в каталоге:

```
/git-data/repositories/root/test.git
```

Сам рабочий сайт располагается на этом же сервере, но лежит в каталоге `/sites/test/`.

Как выгрузить все изменения из ветки `master` (или какой-либо другой, например `qa-release-1.0`) репозитория в рабочую папку сайта (или для ветки `qa-release-1.0` будет другая папка сайта, где расположена тестовая копия сайта)?

Другими словами, как сделать деплой ветки `master` репозитория `test` в каталог `/sites/test/`, а ветки `qa-release-1.0` в каталог `/sites/test-qa/`? (всё это на одной машине)

Comment: Про Builds из gitlab лучше создать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: 1. что значит «загрузить изменения»? 2. вы пишете про каталог на сервере и пишете про gitlab. определитесь — какой доступ вам нужен к этому репозиторию. 3. какое отношение какой-то сайт имеет к репозиторию? // пожалуйста, старайтесь перед тем, как отправите вопрос, оценить, будет ли понятно изложенное в нём кому-либо помимо вас.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, отредактировал, вопрос про gitlab пока убрал, хочу разобраться в том что есть сейчас...

Comment: @sanu0074, дополнил ответ второй версией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не зная, что именно вы подразумеваете под терминами «выгрузить все изменения из ветки» и «сделать деплой ветки», осмелюсь предположить, что вы всего лишь хотите клонировать репозиторий в определённый каталог и переключиться на определённую ветку.

это можно сделать одной командой (клонировать и переключиться):

```
$ git clone -b ветка url_репозитория каталог
```

к примеру:

```
$ git clone -b master /git-data/repositories/root/test.git /sites/test/
$ git clone -b qa-release-1.0 /git-data/repositories/root/test.git /sites/test-qa/
```

подробности — в `man git-clone`.

---

если же верна догадка LazyBadger, то следует воспользоваться командой `archive`:

```
$ git archive --remote=url-репозитория ветка > /путь/к/архиву.tar
```

к примеру (сразу с распаковкой, без создания промежуточного файла):

```
$ git archive --remote=/git-data/repositories/root/test.git master | tar -x -C /sites/test/
$ git archive --remote=/git-data/repositories/root/test.git qa-release-1.0 | tar -x -C /sites/test-qa/
```

подробности — в `man git-archive`.

Comment: Спасибо, @LazyBadger был прав в своих догадках. А про gitlab, я имел ввиду, можно ли как-то из интерфейса gitlab'a выполнять команды `archive` с распаковкой, без создания промежуточного файла? чтобы не ходить на сервер. Поэтому и спрашивал про builds, для чего этот пункт в меню...

Comment: @sanu0074, url-репозитория может быть любой понятный *git-у*. в том числе тот, что предоставляет gitlab, github и т.п.